Alignment of p orbitals of hydrogen atom
Suppose there is an electron with the second lowest energy eigenvalue or in second energy level of hydrogen atom . The probability density of the finding the electron will not be same at all directions but it will be more in certain directions . It will be maximum at the direction of the alignment of p orbitals . If the hydrogen atom is not interacting with anything , the probability density will not change with time . Thus the p orbital are always aligned towards a specific direction . This alignment may be measured experimentally . My question is that for a single point (hydrogen nucleus )all directions are equivalent so  why are probability density polarised towards a specific direction but not others ? Or what factors influence the alignment of orbitals ?

What do you know about eigenfunctions with degenerate eigenvalues? In particular are you aware that if two eigenfunctions have degenerate eigenvalues then any linear combination of those eigenfuntions is also an eigenfunction of the operator with the same eigenvalue?

@IanBush Yes I am aware of that

Hence any linear combination of 2p and 2s hydrogenic orbital is also an eigenfunction, and hence you can have such a function "point" in any direction you want.

@IanBush Yes any linear combination of 2s and 2p are eigenfunctions with same energy eigenvalue .

So there can be infinite kinds of directions where the overall probability density maxima are aligned

Not quite sure I understand what you are getting at but in principle I can prepare the state in an infinite number of ways, so I can align it in a infinite number of ways

@IanBush I am understanding what you are saying . Let there be a dice of infinite sides with different numbers written on each side . We role it and get 55 . My question is like why we get 55 not any other number when all numbers are equivalent or equally likely .

If so then I think there cannot be an answer .

You seem to be assuming that the specific alignment observed in the measurement exists prior to measurement (based on "Thus the p orbital are always aligned towards a specific direction "). As with almost any QM measurement, that is not the case.

I guess you should talk in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/155633/discussion-between-users-and-ian-bush Dunno why it's not autolinked

But you are correct that we do not have an answer to why QM systems behave probabilistically rather than deterministically. We simply know that all of our empirical results are consistent with the former rather than the latter.
